# C: parse char array of digits separated by characters and turn digits into integers

Tags: c, string, bioinformatics, atoi

I have a problem with some strings created by a sequence alignment program (this is a bioinformatics project). I am attempting to add additional functionality to an existing C program that parses alignment files but I've run into some issues with the parsing of a "mis match" string that the program creates. To add some context, here is an example of the alignment string:

example = "28G11AC10T32";

Here is how to interpret the string: the first 28 bases match the sequence, then there is a "G" mismatch (29th base total), the next 11 bases match (40th base total), an "A" mismatch (41st base total), "C" mismatch (42nd base total), and so on...

I need to find out the base position where there are mismatches (ie, the string has a character instead of digits) and store that into an int array so that I can look this up in a later subroutine.

So here is where my issue comes into play. I have written a subroutine that I "thought" could parse this out, but I get a very strange artifact from the output. NOTE: please forgive my terrible and cluttered code! I am not a C programmer by any means and my training is not in computer science!

```
int errorPosition(char *mis_match, int *positions){
    int i = 0; //iterator for loop
    int pi = 0; //position array iterator
    int in = 0; //makeshift boolean to tell if values are inside the pre array
    int con = 0; //temporary holder for values converted from the pre array
    char pre[5]; //this array will hold the digit values that will be converted to ints
    pre[0] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(mis_match); i++){
        if(isalpha(mis_match[i]) && in == 1){
            con += atoi(pre);   // this is the part where I get an artifact (see below)
            positions[pi] = con;
            con++;
            pi++;
            in = 0;
            memset(&pre[0], 0, sizeof(pre));
            pri = 0;
        }else if(isalpha(mis_match[i]) && in == 0){
            positions[pi] = con;
            con++;
            pi++;
        }else if(isdigit(mis_match[i])){
            pre[pri] = mis_match[i];
            pri++;
            in = 1;
        }
    }
    if(pri > 0){
        con += atoi(pre);
        positions[pi] = con;
        pi++;
    }

}
```

So, my issue is that when I reach the segment that I have commented above ("this is where I get the error"), my "pre" string contains the digits times 10. For example, using the example string I listed above, the first time that the loop would reach that area I would expect that pre would contain "28", but instead it contains "280"! When I use atoi to convert the string, it is therefore ten times higher than I expect. 
Is there something that I am missing or some char array convention in C that I am ignorant of here? Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the only issue, but you are not zero-terminating the string that you pass to `atoi`. The `'0'` character in the third position of `280` may be garbage, because you never wrote to that position of the array.

To address this issue, you should add this line before the call of `atoi`:

```
pre[pri] = '\0';
```

Comment: Gah! The simplest stuff, right? Thank you very much for your reply! The ints are now correct and the program works!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will extract (and print) the numeric & non-numeric portions of your string; you can adapt it to do what you need to with those portions.

```
char* example = "28G11AC10T32";
int pos = 0;
int value = 0;
while ( 1 ) {
    if ( !isdigit(example[pos]) ) {
        if ( value > 0 )
            printf( "Number = %d\n", value );
        value = 0;
        if ( example[pos]==0 )
            break;
        else
            printf( "Char = %c\n", example[pos] );
    } else {
        value = value * 10 + example[pos]-'0';
    }
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Far more elegant than my amateur solution. Thank you as well!